# Populate data from mysql in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I am developing and android app that retrieves news from mysql database and populate them in list view, i managed to retrieve data successfully but am facing one major problem that stops me from proceeding with my project. When i try to populate data in listview  the app crashes in displaying the following error in log cat saying

```
your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I have tried to change my xml listview id and write it in different forms but it still fails and displaying same error.
here are my xml codes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/read_news"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:baselineAligned="false" />


</LinearLayout>
```

here are my java codes

```
package com.jetas.sportsapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.jetas.sportsapp.utils.JsonUtils;

public class News extends ListActivity {
//   private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mCommentList;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_single_post);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newsList = getData();
    updateList(newsList);
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getData() {
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
    try {

//          String s = "";
        String news =     
    JsonUtils.read("http://10.0.2.2/index.php/android/news?offset=0&limit=10");
        Log.d("News data",news);
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(news);

        Log.d("Parsing json", jArray.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = json.getString("title");
            String content = json.getString("content");

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("title", title);
            map.put("content", content);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            mCommentList.add(map);

//              textview.setText(title);
//              s = s + "Title: " + json.getString("title") + "\n"
//                      + "Content: " + json.getString("content") +     
"\n\n";
//              textview.setText(s);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data" + e.toString());
        textview.setText("Error in Parsing Data !!!!!");
    }
        return mCommentList;
}

/**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> newsLists) {
        // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order   
                    //  to do
        //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
        //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
        //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
        //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
        //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, newsLists,
                R.layout.news_single_post, new String[] { "title", 
                    "content"}, new int[] { R.id.newsTitle, R.id.content,});

        // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
        //could do something.  However, we will choose
        //to do nothing...
        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // This method is triggered if an item is click 
                                    // within our
                // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
                // it is useful to know in real life applications.

            }
        });

    }   

//      public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
//
//          @Override
//          protected void onPreExecute() {
//              super.onPreExecute();
//              pDialog = new ProgressDialog(News.this);
//              pDialog.setMessage("Loading Comments...");
//              pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
//              pDialog.setCancelable(true);
//              pDialog.show();
//          }
//          @Override
//          protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
//              //we will develop this method in version 2
//              getData();
//              return null;
//
//          }
//
//
//          @Override
//          protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
//              super.onPostExecute(result);
//              pDialog.dismiss();
//            //we will develop this method in version 2
//              updateList();
//          }
    }
```

I also want to set such that when user clicks on the news the new activity opens with the details of the news.

Comment: Listview id xml should hava     ===> android:id="@android:id/list"

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

Change this `android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"` to `android:id="@android:id/list"` like below

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and solved by following

```
Listview lv;
lv = (listview) Findviewbyid(android.R.id.listviewname);
```